# In PHP why does \Foo\Bar::class not generate an error when the class doesn't exist?

Tags: php, class

Why does

```php
<?php
namespace Foo;
echo Bar::class;
```

output `Foo\Bar` **without** any errors, warnings, or notices? I would have expected some sort of "Class does not exist" message.

Comment: interesting... and already noticed by developers: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From PHP's [document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)

> The class name resolution using ::class is a compile time
>   transformation. That means at the time the class name string is
>   created no autoloading has happened yet. As a consequence, class names
>   are expanded even if the class does not exist. **No error** is issued in
>   that case.

So, it is documented and an expected behavior

Comment: Yes it is bloody true :>